# How to parse lines of code with multiple data types

Tags: java, exception, file-io, binary

Currently working on a program that reads in stats from football players and converts the data to binary and writes it all to a file.  The problem I have been having is parsing all the different data types that the file I'm reading in contains. The file I am reading in will have the following format - lastName  yearsExp  position  height  weight  40ydSpeed  team  active? An example of what this will look like is the file is the following: Brady, 14, QB, 1, 210, 4.9, Patriots, true
I am wondering how to go about parsing the different data types, int, char, double, String, and boolean.

So far my program asks the user to enter a file and it catches any FileNotFoundExceptions from invalid files and loops until a valid file is entered. Then the program reads the file and stores it all into a list.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     File file;
     Scanner inputFile;
     Scanner readFile;
     String line;
     String fileName;
     int x = 1;

     ArrayList<String> stats = new ArrayList<String>();

    do {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the name of a " +
                "file containing football player data:");
        fileName = kb.nextLine();

        try {
            file = new File(fileName);
            inputFile = new Scanner(file);
            while(inputFile.hasNext()) {

                    stats.add(inputFile.nextLine());
            }
            x=2;

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
            System.out.print("File not found. ");
            }
       }
    while(x==1);

    for (String s : stats) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // TODO use the following methods for writing to binary
    // TODO writeUTF, writeInt, writeChar, writeInt, writeInt, writeDbl, writeByte
```

Comment: Looks like the values are separated by commas, so I'd suggest you use a **CSV parser** (CSV = Comma-Separated-Values).

Comment: In my opinion you should create a Player class and use that. You will most likely need it later to work with the data anyways.

Answer (score 2):

> how to go about parsing the different data types, int, char, double, String, and boolean

In order:

```
int x = Integer.parseInt(s)
char x = s.charAt(0)
double x = Double.parseDouble(s)
String x = s
boolean x = Boolean.parseBoolean(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current problem is tha `ArrayList<String> stats = new ArrayList<String>();` forces any of the values you read to be `String`. If you've learned about classes, then you can create a class that models a football player: let's call it `FootballPlayer` as an example.

In `FootballPlayer` you would have many fields of different types. You would have one for `lastName` that is a `String`, `yearsExp` that is an `int`, etc.

Then, here:

```
 while(inputFile.hasNext()) {
     stats.add(inputFile.nextLine());
 }
```

You could keep an index corresponding to what field you are trying to read. `lastName` could correspond to `index` 0, `yearsExpr` to 1, etc. Then, based on the index value (you could use a `switch` statement), you could call a different method of `Scanner` that returns the appropiate type, like `nextInt()`, if the index if 1 (for `yearsExpr`). After calling this appropiate method, you would assign the returned value to the corresponding field in your instance of `FootballPlayer`.

In the future, this whole process could be handled for you by using a library to parse the data format you're using, like a CSV parser (as it appears you data is comma-separated).

Answer (score 0):

You could split the input by the `,` or any other common delimiter separating them, then try to parse each one by one.

```java
String input = "Tom, 15, 6, 86.4"; // name, age, grade, mark
String[] inputs = input.split(", "); // [ Tom, 15, 6, 86.4 ]

for (String in : inputs) {
    if (isInteger(in)) {
        // something
    } else if (isString(in)) {
        // other thing
    } // etc
}
```